# Is Jetty websocket client class WebSocketClient thread safe?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, client, jetty-9

Jetty 9.3

Java 8

Is `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient` thread safe.

Can multiple threads use a single instance of this class to create a websocket session (with the `connect` method) ?

Answer (score 4):

I can't guarantee that `WebSocketClient` is 100% thread safe, but I can say that it is meant to be thread safe, to a certain extent.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java), we see that the private method [`initializeClient`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java#L445) is synchronized:

```
private synchronized void initializeClient() throws IOException
```

and that the [`connect`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java#L157) method is using an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html):

```
// Execute the connection on the executor thread
executor.execute(promise);
```

The documentation of the class says nothing about thread safety, but the call of the synchronized `initializeClient` method from the `connect` method and the use of the `Executor` are clear signs that some form of multi-threading is supported.

== Edit ==

Thread safety is often guaranteed only for certain types of operations. For examples it can be guaranteed only for read operations and not for write operations. This is the role of the documentation to define the conditions of thread safety. The remark of Sergio Montoro is right, if one thread modify the object during its use by another thread, strange things could happens. In the case of `WebSocketClient` thread safety is certainly at least restricted to the non-modification of the object by other threads, or to the synchronized and concerted modification of the `WebSocketClient` internal state.

Comment: +1 WebSocketClient is definitely written to be thread-safe. The fact that _code can sometimes contain bugs_ doesn't mean that this isn't multithreaded code.

Answer (score 4):

It's not, from [the code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/jetty.project/jetty-9.3.x/jetty-websocket/websocket-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java) here is at least one example why:

The purpose of `WebSocketClient` is to provide a mean of establishing connections to remote websocket endpoints.

This is achieved by calling `connect()` method, which returns Future Session. All right, now imagine that

1. Thread 1 instantiates a `WebSocketClient` and calls `setCookieStore()`
2. Thread 1 calls `connect(Object websocket, URI toUri)`.
3. Inside `connect()` Thread 1 executes

   ```
   ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest(toUri)
   ```

   and

   ```
   request.setRequestURI(toUri)
   ```
4. Thread 2 executes `setCookieStore(CookieStore cookieStore)`

Then the request created by Thread 1 may have the cookies corresponding to the URI of Thread 2.

In order to ensure thread safety the internal state of the object should de unmodifiable during the whole connection process.

Comment: Not sure the cookie Store in the WebSocketClient is here to set the common cookie that should be shared between the different calls. The per request cookie should be set with setCookies on the ClientUpgradeRequest.

Comment: If cookieStore was meant to be shared across threads then it should be declared `volatile`. Otherwise a thread could change the value and the other don't see the change. Also I don't see in the class how to keep two sets of cookies: the shared among threads subset and the per-thread subset. Moreover, is it possible to think of a reasonable use case for splitting cookies this way in two subsets?